# How can I output this function on a browser?

Tags: browser, html, javascript

The function outputs correctly on online code editors but I am not successful in replicating the output on my browser. What's the correct way of outputting it to my browser? I have tried numerous methods. Here is the function I want to output.

```js
function countdown(i) {
    console.log(i);  
    if (i <= 1) {  // base case
        return;
    } else {     // recursive case
        countdown(i - 1);
    }
}

countdown(5);    // This is the initial call to the function.
```

Here is my most recent attempt at output on my web browser

```js
function countDown(i) {
    document.getElementById("recursiveFuncAttempt").innerHTML = i;
    if (i <= 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        cat = countDown(i - 1);
        return document.getElementById("recursiveFuncAttempt").innerHTML = cat;
        
    }
}
countDown(5);
```

```html
<div>
    countdown attempt
    <button onclick="countDown()">click me</button>
    <p id="recursiveFuncAttempt"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked fine for me in the browser, running it in Firefox DevTools Console. What have you tried? What was the error you encountered?

Comment: Here's my latest attempt at outputting it to my browser                                            function countDown(i) {
 document.getElementById("recursiveFuncAttempt").innerHTML = i;
 if (i <= 1) {
  return;
 } else {
  cat = countDown(i - 1);
  return document.getElementById("recursiveFuncAttempt").innerHTML = i;
  
 }
}
countDown(5);

Comment: Your "attempt" has a completely different logic / heuristic. Why would you add an extra `cat` and return in the `else` clause?

Comment: Many attempts led me to that. What is the proper way to go about it?

Comment: Besides with `log()` you will see multiple lines of output, but when you update the content of a web page, you are modifying the same element and there's no real-time delay implemented.

Comment: Can I see a working example with the codes? I can't seem to figure this out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping your code and the comments together...

1. Your original code was correct but instead of logging to the console you should add the value to the [text content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of a page element.
2. Logging the different values in the console - line by line - gives an appearance of time passing which updating the text content of a DOM element wouldn't give you. All you would see is the last digit in the sequence because the function would work faster than your eyes can see.

   Therefore a [a timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) is needed to pause execution for *n* time before calling the function again.
3. You can simplify the code a little by eliminating the `else` part of the condition.

```js
// Cache the element
const div = document.querySelector('div');

// Add a default value to count if a value
// is not passed into the function
function countdown(count = 5) {

  // If count is zero just return
  if (count < 1) return;

  // Otherwise update the text content
  // of the cached element
  div.textContent = count;

  // Wait one second (1000ms), and call the function
  // with a decremented count
  setTimeout(countdown, 1000, --count);

}

countdown();
```

```css
div { font-size: 5em; color: blue; font-weight: 700;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works however my initial attempt was to implement it using a Recursive function.

Comment: It _is_ recursive. It calls `countdown` repeatedly when the timeout has passed until the count has reached zero. @ZeroHour